# PyQt Greek letters encoding

Tags: python, qt, unicode, pyqt

I have a python program and I am using `pyqt`. I use `QFileDialog` to select directory and then run a script with that directory. The problem is that if the directory name is in Greek the program stops with exception

```
ascii codec can't encode characters in position
```

If the name of the directory is in English everything works fine.
How can i solve that?

```
try:
            directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(MainWindow,"Please select directory ") #Select the directory for check   

            if directory != "":
                directory = str(directory)

                self.updatedirectory(directory)
        except Exception as e:    
            self.AlertMessage(e)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 3):

Consider telling PyQt to use native Python unicode strings

Before you import PyQt, insert:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
```

`QtCore.QString` will no longer exist (you will get exceptions if you try and manually create a `QString`) and all PyQt methods that previously returned a `QString` will return a Python unicode string.

Note: Don't try to typecast the unicode string with `str()`. Just use the result of `getExistingDirectory` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `str()` to convert a `QString`: always use `unicode()`:

```
    directory = unicode(directory)
```

In Python 2, `str()` converts to *bytes*. If you use it on a string object containing unicode, it will try to encode it using the default codec, which is "ascii". So, if the string contains non-ascii characters, you will obviously get an error:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> s = QtCore.QString(u'Γειά σου Κόσμε!')
>>> x = str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

but if you use `unicode()`, it will convert the `QString` to a python unicode object directly (i.e. without needing to do any encoding/decoding):

```
>>> x = unicode(s)
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print x
Γειά σου Κόσμε!
```

Answer (score 1):

[`QtGui.QFileDialog`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) returns a [`QString`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html), if you want to extract the `string` out of it, use one of its methods, for instance [`QString.toLatin1`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#toLatin1).

**EXAMPLE:**

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
>>>
>>> s = QString(u'Γεια σου')
>>> 
>>> s
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\xce\x93\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb1 \xcf\x83\xce\xbf\xcf\x85')
>>> print s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    print s
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
>>>print str(s.toLatin())
Γεια σου
```

There are other methods that you might want to try to get your desired output.

So, in your case, this might work for you:

```
directory = str(directory.toLatin())
```

Comment: @AgisSoleas .. can you do `print directory` and post into your question before you do `str(directory)` ?

Comment: if i try to print before str i get ascii codec can't encode characters in position

Comment: also if try to use directory.encode('utf8') i get error QString object has no attribute encode

Comment: Can u try `directory.toUtf8()` instead of `directory.toLatin1()`?

Comment: if i print it before the str() i get \╬Σ╧Δ╧Η╬υ╬╗╬╡╬╣╬▒ ╬Φ╬╣╬║╧Ε╧Ξ╧Κ╬╜ and after str i get error str has no attribute toUtf8()

Comment: No..don't do `toUtf8` or `toLatin1` after you do `str`, since those two methods are for `QString` object not `string` object. That's why you get `str i get error str has no attribute toUtf8()` error message

Comment: Then, can you try this: `directory = unicode(directory.toUtf8())` then `print directory` ?

Comment: i did reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') and now i can print it in terminal but in my QtGui the problem hasnt solved. i get error ||||\\\? near syntax error